# Copy and Delete

Tags: bash, ubuntu, move, dir, delete-file

Ok, I am new to ubuntu. I have 200,000 files that I need to go through and archive files that have not been updated in 30days.

```
find . -type f -mtime +30
```

Done.

Then I need to copy them to a location while keeping their dir structure past the current ./ This is because the file structure is part of the uniqueness of each file. I may have 200 files called sum however FunRun/Sum and Smoke/Sum are two different things.

```
find . -type f -mtime +30 -exec cp --parents '{}' /home/me/backup \;
```

Done. But that does not delete them... Well mv is a cp with delete. But MV does not have --parents switch.

So I tried

```
find . -type f -mtime +30 -exec cp --parents '{}' /home/me/backup \; && rm
for file in 'find . -type f -mtime +30' do sudo cp $file --parents '{}' /home/me/backup \; && sudo rm $file; done
```

No go. So I was playing with creating a list of files and use it like old school batch files. Problem is the list takes a long time to make and I would like to automate this process. So I searched and tested nothing worked. So either a one-line bash script is a lost cause and will need to write a python script to do it or you guys can help. So I figured I would ask here and see how it goes over the weekend and test on monday.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is that last "So I tried" two separate commands? In the first one, where are you expecting the arguments to `rm` to come from? Why did you add `sudo` in the second one? Where's the `;` or newline in your `for`? Where do you expect the `'{}'` to come from in the second line, and why do you want anything there when you already have `$file`? (Also, why no quotes anywhere?)

Comment: Yes it was two separate commands. 
I added sudo because when I try to copy it around I get you need root level access error. As far as the rest I am trying to learn and am poking around to try and get it to work on my test server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you're doing looks like shotgun debugging attempts—just changing random things without really knowing what they mean. You should really read through a tutorial on `find`, and maybe one on bash scripting.

---

Anyway, you can string together multiple actions on a single `find` command. Even multiple `-exec` actions if you want. So:

```
find . -type f -mtime +30 -exec cp --parents '{}' /home/me/backup \; -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Or, more simply:

```
find . -type f -mtime +30 -exec cp --parents '{}' /home/me/backup \; -delete
```

Or, of course, you could write your own two-line shell script that calls `cp --parents` with all of its arguments, then calls `rm` with all but its last argument, and just `-exec` that.

---

If you want to do the `for` loop, you can do that… although `xargs` would probably make for sense than doing them one by one, let's try it your way:

- You're not calling `find` at all; single quotes mark literal strings. If you want to execute a string as a command and get the results, you want *backticks*. Or, better, `$(…)`.
- A one-liner `for` loop needs a semicolon before the `do`.
- You've added `sudo`, which wasn't in your `find` commands, so I doubt you want it here either.
- Using `$file` without quotes is a bad idea if you have any files with, say, spaces in the names.
- The `'{}'` and `\;` are going to pass literal `{}` and `;` strings to `cp`. So, you're asking it to copy `$file`, `{}`, and `/home/me/backup` to `;`. That doesn't make any sense. The `find` command has special uses for those things, but `cp` doesn't. If you're using `'{}'` to try to pass the filename, you're already doing that with `$file`.

So:

```
for file in $(find . -type f -mtime +30); do cp "$file" --parents /home/me/backup && sudo rm "$file"; done
```

Comment: Yes, I am a novice to ubuntu and bash. I have 10 years on windows and about 2 days on ubuntu. I did read some tutorials that is how I got a far as I did. Do you recommend any really good bash scripting tutorials? Never know what ones are good or bad when you are just learning.

I will try these out today and let you know. =) thanks for your time so far.

Comment: @user1519219: No idea; I learned bash from a tutorial meant for sh/ksh users. And I don't think it was a very good one; decades later I still often do things the clunky ksh way even when bash has a better solution. :) If Google isn't good enough, maybe try asking on a Unix/Linux/Ubuntu mailing list or forum?

Comment: I ran your first scripts. I had to add sudo to the cp and delete but it worked on my dev box. I am going to test it on production later today. Thank you Is there a way to keep the modified date of the copied file?

Comment: @user1519219: Well, not _just_ the modified date, but if you're happy to keep all three dates (ctime and atime as well as mtime, and possibly bonus dates like birthtime) you can use `--preserve=timestamps`. Or, if you want something more cross-platform, and you're happy to keep all the dates plus mode and ownership, use `-p`.

Comment: You are amazing, I got some free time I am going to work on this today.

Comment: Worked amazing. I also tar it up.  Thanks. If you get a moment I do not understand what '{}' and \; do.

Comment: @user1519219: Actually, if you're also tarring up the files, you may want to consider _not_ doing the `cp`, but instead just untarring the tarball at the end. `tar` preserves modtimes by default—and at least BSDtar and GNUtar (you probably have one of those) give you even more precise flags than `cp` to control exactly what metadata you preserve.

Comment: @user1519219: As for `'{}'` and `\;`: Those are part of the `find` command. The `-exec` action takes every argument up to the first semicolon, substitutes in a found filename or list of filenames for any `{}` argument, and executes it as a sub-command. The quotes and backslash are to escape the `;` and `{}`, because if you don't do that, the shell may give them special meaning (e.g., with `bash`, a semicolon is used as a command terminator; you don't want that, you want the semicolon to be given to `find` as an argument, so you need to escape it from `bash`).